# How does my program run without including necessary .c files?

Tags: c, include

I am coding in C and in an attempt to organize my program and make it cleaner, I took all the functions out of main.c and put them in their own .c files which all include the header.h. I forgot to include all the .c files in my main.c and when I compiled the program, it still ran perfectly! How is this possible? Do you not need to include .c files that are in the same folder? Should I still include the .c files anyway to be safe?

Comment: What compiler?  How are you compiling?  Sometimes a make file might specify something like *.c.

Comment: By include, do you mean link? If so, yes, you should always link all necessary C files. If by include, you mean `#include file.c`, then no, you should not include other C files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have any number of c files you want, at compile time object files are generated and then linked togaether making the executable binary.

While including the c files in your `main.c` could work, it's not the appropriate way to split the program in different files, the correct way is to compile all the files into an intermidiate represantation called Object Files, and then the linker links them all togaether to make the executable binary.

So compilation goes like this

```
file1.c -> file1.o
file2.c -> file2.o
file3.c -> file3.o
file4.c -> file4.o

        .
        .
        .
        .
```

and then a linking stage which takes all the files

```
file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o  ... -> executable-binary-file
```

You could also pass all the c files to the compiler at once.

Comment: Ahh this is a very good explanation of how compiling works. So what happens with interpreted languages like Python then?

Comment: @James4701 interpreted languages need the interpreter to run, python generates some files called bytecode with .pyc extension that allows python to execute the scripts faster, but you can't generate native executable binaries with programs written in interpreted languages.

Answer (score 0):

You're *not supposed* to include the other .c files in main.c

A C compiler will compile each .c file into .o files, separately.

And then it's the job of the linker to put the resulting objects files back together in a single executable.

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this answer as soon as I can.